# Installation of gromacs and VMD in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, vmd

I had installed both gromacs and vmd in ubuntu 15.10, and they worked fine. But after I upgrade to ubuntu 14.04 I couldn't install them again, vmd can't have been extracted. I installed cmake and FFTW prior to install gromacs. I can see that cmake is installed but gromacs doesn't exist.
Now I upgraded to ubuntu 16.04, but still can't install them.

```
      $ tar -zxvf vmd-1.9.2.bin.LINUXAMD64.opengl.tar.gz 

      gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
      tar: Child returned status 1
      tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Thanks

Comment: gromacs appears to be in the Universe repo of 16.04 - see http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gromacs

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for response   I updated then I make the universe repository enabled, also I downloaded (pymol and gromacs-data..) then installed them, after that I reinstalled gromacs, but nothing change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer 
use `tar xvf` instead of `tar -zxvf`
but I don not know what is the problem, but I successfully installed VMD this way.

Comment: There are different implementations of tar and ways of using it. tar xvf is the modern way